# ReactJS/Node.JS project not working in Vercel (500)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, vercel, http-status-code-500

I would really use some help with this bad boy.

I made a World Cup prediction web app using ReactJS and Node.js for the API. It works beautifully in my local machine, but as I deployed to Vercel I've been dealing with some issues.

I don't think it has something to do with my environment variables, as the user can sign up and log in normally. The problem is when it tries to get this user's predicted scores (or "guesses") list.

At entering the dashboard, Vercel's realtime log returns me the following:

[image: Vercel's realtime log]

I'm a bit stuck in this error and would gladly share any code or screenshots that might provide additional info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks to be an issue with your prisma (db) configuration. Looks like you're trying to access a table called "(not available)". I'd start looking there.

Answer (score 1):

The database connecting to the app does not have 'guess' table(or collection). it seems like you forgot `yarn prisma migrate deploy` to the database. Or before starting app, you should run `yarn prisma generate` to create `@prisma/client` types.(`yarn` can be changed npx or whatever you use)

Comment: Well, this is embarassing... apparently I've made some minor changes in my db (one of them being the guesses table name) and forgot to deploy the changes from dev to main, so the correct table could never be reached. It looks like is working just fine now. Thank you guys so much!